# Can't connect to websocket through proxy

Tags: java, http, websocket, proxy, okhttp

I'm trying to connect to a websocket through my own http proxy using Java's `okhttp3` library.

I've set up the proxy on an EC2 instance and have configured the security groups correctly. I'm able to confirm that it works:

```
time curl -s --proxy http://X.X.X.X:8888 https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ping

real    0m0.597s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.008s
```

However, my attempts to connect to a websocket through the proxy have failed. Below is the code.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .proxy(new Proxy(Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("X.X.X.X", 8888)))
        .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("wss://fstream.binance.com/stream")
        .build();

WebSocket webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, new WebSocketListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(final WebSocket webSocket, final Throwable t, final Response response) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }   
});
```

If I remove the line `.proxy(new Proxy(Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("X.X.X.X", 8888)))`, then it works perfectly well, but if I have that line, I get the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 403
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.createTunnel(RealConnection.kt:447)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTunnel(RealConnection.kt:235)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:170)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:236)
...
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:184)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I'm at a loss as to what to do? I can access the proxy through terminal but can't connect to a websocket through it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. My `tinyproxy` config file wasn't allowing my IP address.